# ¿Como puedo mostrar los resultados de una consulta sql dentro de un modal?

Tags: php, html, sql, bootstrap

**Explico:** Tengo un modal que se abre por medio de una etiqueta , al momento de hacer click, no muestra los resultados de la sentencia sql.

Realizo la conexion a la base de datos en el head. Guardo un dato de una consulta anterior para poder realizar otra consulta con ese dato. Al momento de mostrar los resultados el modal me abre vació. les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

```html
//se genera un botón por cada registro
<td><a whatever='@fat' data-toggle='modal' class='btn btn-success' data-target='#visual$row[IDresguardo]'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> Ver Registros</a></td></tr>

// modal
<div class="modal fade" id="visual<?php echo $row['IDresguardo'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
     <div style="background-color: #4E9C3D;" class="modal-header bg-primary">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title " id="myModalLabel"> <label>mostrar registros de BD</label></h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">

                                                        
                                                    
           <?php  
        $fecha1=$row[fecha];                                                 
        $mostrarc=mysql_query("select r.fecha, r.tipo, hi.cantidad ,h.descripcionB from herramienta h, historial hi, resguardo r where  hi.NoHerramienta=h.NoHerramienta and hi.RPEtrab='.$rpe.' and r.fecha='.$fecha1.'");


          echo "<table>";
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<th>fech</th>";
          echo "<th>tipo</th>";
          echo "<th>Cantidad</th>";
          echo "<th>descripcionB</th>";
          echo "</tr>";

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($mostrarc)) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          }
          echo "</table>";
                                                       

         ?>

                                                    
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
                                        
         </div>
```

Comment: Amigo ¿ puedes colgar tu pregunta de una manera más amigable? El  extracto de código que intentas mostrar es indescifrable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el modal te vuelve vació, intenta de otra forma. Agrega:

```
<?php
    include "archivo.php";
    error_reporting(E_ALL); //Verificar si hay errores
?>
```

Entre las etiquetas de apertura y cierre del Modal.
 Y en ese archivo pon el codigo de la consulta o lo que quieras mostrar en el modal.

Verifica que el código dentro del modal, funcione sin el modal, capaz puedes tener algun error en lo que es la primer consulta o en la segunda.
Veo que utilizas `mysql`, se recomienda utilizar `mysqli` [docs](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.summary.php)

Yo lo utilizo asi. [(Con Bootstrap Modal)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Comment: muchas gracias, me mostró un error en la consulta y la conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: De nada, yo siempre compruebo con el `error_reporting(E_ALL);` para no tener fallas cuando manejo muchos `archivos.php` .

Comment: gracias, solo una pregunta más,.. necesito pasar unas variables de php al archivo.php que acabo de crear, pero uno de esos valores proviene de una consulta sql, pero no la puedo pasar por medio de la url, ¿como la puedo pasar por otro metodo?. Esto es lo quiero pasar a archivo.php     $r1=$row['tipos'];

Comment: Puedes generar la consulta y almacenar ese valor de la consulta en una $variable y luego, pasarla junto a la otra variable al archivo. ¿Eso quieres decir?

Comment: si, tengo este valor $variable=$row['tipos']; y necesito pasarla al archivo.php, ¿como  podria pasarla?

Comment: Puedes enviarlas mediante `$_GET` o  `$_POST`,

Answer (score 0):

El código es bastante desordenado y no se sabe bien que estás haciendo pero traduciendo un poco este desastre al parecer estás haciendo esto:

```
<?php

echo "tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"> × mostrar registros de BD " 
. ""
. "fech"
. "tipo"
. "Cantidad"
. "descripcionB"
. "";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($mostrarc)) {
   echo "" 
   . "".$row[0]
   . ""
   . "" 
   . $row[1] 
   . "" 
   . "" 
   . $row[2] 
   . "" 
   . "" 
   . $row[3] 
   . "" 
   . ""; 

} 
echo ""; 
?>
```

Y eso se traduce a esto:

```
<?php

echo "tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"> × mostrar registros de BD fechtipoCantidaddescripcionB";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($mostrarc)) {
   echo $row[0] . $row[1] . $row[2] . $row[3]; 
} 
?>
```

En la primer línea tienes errores con los delimitadores del string, deberías usar lo siguiente:

```
echo 'tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"> × mostrar registros de BD "fech" "tipo" "Cantidad" "descripcionB"';
```

Tomando en cuenta estos errores lo más seguro es que `$mostrarc` tenga errores similares, revisa tu query. También aprecio que estás usando las funciones `mysql_` y estas están descontinuadas, usa `mysqli_` en su lugar. Revisa la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.summary.php).

**FORMATEA TU CÓDIGO SIEMPRE**, será más fácil entenderlo y encontrar errores de esa manera.

Por último, dentro de tu loop `while` puedes arrojar todo el resultado de tu query para asegurarte que estás obteniendo resultados:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($mostrarc)) {
  echo var_export($row, true);
}
```

Comment: Te agradezco por la respuesta, pero no me funciono tu recomendación. me devuelve el modal vacio. La consulta esta funcionando, ya que hice la prueba en mysql Workbench y la sentencia es correcta.